# How can you make a div stick to the edge of a container at all times?

Tags: html, css

Making a website. It consists of one main container in the center and a sidebar. I only know how to make the sidebar be on the far left or right of the screen. What I want to do though is make the sidebar stick to the left of my main container. Is there a way of doing this?

The sidebar is just a flexbox with a few links and images in it.

```css
#container {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 100px;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" style="float: left">
  <p>Sidebar</p>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <p>Container</p>
</div>
```

I tried using `float:left` but that just makes the sidebar go to the very edge of the page. What I need is the sidebar to sort of stick to the container.

[image]

[Diagram of what I have vs what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLEuR.png)

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS so we can have a look so we can give you a satisfactory answer.  Have a look at the SO guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to create a minimal reproducible example. Ta.

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS so far in a [mre]. Also, what happens when you scroll, is the sidebar "stuck" to the top edge of the blue element, or should it remain visible and slide down the left edge?

Comment: Sorry! Will add HTML to my question in a second.
Also, the sidebar should be stuck to the top edge of the blue element.

Comment: Does the container have to be positioned to the center of the viewport?

Comment: Yep. But if it makes it harder to implement a sidebar like this, it doesn't have to be

Comment: No problem. See answer below

Comment: What widths/heights are fixed and what can change? Is the content guaranteed to be taller than sidebar?

Comment: The content is guaranteed to be taller, yeah. It's alright though. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the container to be centered then you can use css grid to create 3 columns. We make the two side columns `1fr` so they're equal width then the middle column to be `fit-content`. We can then use `align-self` to push the side bar to the edge of the container.  [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) has a great primer on grid and Kevin Powell has a useful video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU)

Example below:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
}

/* we've enclosed the two divs in to wrapper so we can use CSS grid */
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr fit-content(0) 1fr;
  align-items: start; /* place items to the top of the container */
}

#container {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 100px;
}

#sidebar {
  justify-self: end; /* push the sidebar to the right so it butts up next to the container */
  background-color: #ed1c24;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* just some prettification */
.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>Sidebar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <p>Container</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox layout since it is versatile enough for most cases. Add a third column that has same proportions as the first one; that way all three columns will be sized and centered properly. The following example uses a pseudo element as the third column:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 200px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

#wrapper::after {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
  content: 'I am a pseudo element';
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>Sidebar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <p>Container</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
height:300px;
width:300px;
border:1px solid black;
}

.sidebar{
height:100px;
width:100px;
border:1px solid red;
margin: 10px auto;
position:relative;
}

.content{
height:50px;
width:50px;
border:1px solid green;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Main Div
<div class="sidebar">Content
<div class="content">Side box div</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When answering questions, It's good practice to provide an explanation to your code.  It helps the original contributor and anyone reading your answer in future understand how you've solved their problem. If you want those upvotes then it's a good idea to explain your code. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple steps:

1. Position the sidebar at the top left of the container
2. Move the sidebar left equal to it's width

First, to position the sidebar in the top left of the container, we can make the `#container`'s position `relative` so that other things can be `absolute`ly positioned relative to it, then we can position the `#sidebar` `absolute`ly in the top left.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Next, we can move the sidebar to the left equal to it's width:

```css
#sidebar {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```